# Pandas loc error due to missing labels in csv file

Tags: python, pandas

I'm looking at the Choropleth tutorial [here](https://ramiro.org/notebook/basemap-choropleth/).

When I tried to run it I got the following error for line `df = df.ix[iso3_codes].dropna()`:

```
AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'ix'
```

It seems `ix` has been deprecated in Pandas.

I then changed the line to `df = df.loc[iso3_codes].dropna()`  but am getting this error:

```
KeyError: 'Passing list-likes to .loc or [] with any missing labels is no longer supported
```

How do I resolve this?

**Additional information**

I tried `df = df.loc[:, iso3_codes].dropna()` but it give me this error:

```
KeyError: "None of [Index(['AND', 'ARE', 'AFG', 'ATG',.....'ANT'],\n      dtype='object', length=252)] are in the [columns]"
```

Perhaps `loc` is of no use for filtering out non-countries and missing values. How can I do this now?

**Full code**

```py
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import slug

from geonamescache import GeonamesCache
from matplotlib.patches import Polygon
from matplotlib.collections import PatchCollection
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap

filename = 'csv/API_AG.LND.FRST.ZS_DS2_en_csv_v2_988532/API_AG.LND.FRST.ZS_DS2_en_csv_v2_988532.csv'
shapefile = 'shapes/countries/countries/ne_10m_admin_0_countries_lakes'
num_colors = 9
year = '2012'
cols = ['Country Name', 'Country Code', year]
title = f'Forest area as percentage of land area in {format(year)}'
imgfile = f'img{slug.slug(title)}.png'

description = '''
Forest area is land under natural or planted strands of trees of at least 5 meters in situ, whether productive or not,
and excludes tree strands in agricultural production systems(for example, in fruit plantations and agroforestry systems)
and trees in urban parks and gardens. Countries without data are shown in grey.
Data: World Bank - worldbank.org | Author: Ramiro Gómez - ramiro.org
'''.strip()

gc = GeonamesCache()
iso3_codes = list(gc.get_dataset_by_key(gc.get_countries(), 'iso3').keys())

df = pd.read_csv(filename, skiprows=4, usecols=cols)
df.set_index('Country Code', inplace=True)
df = df.loc[:, iso3_codes].dropna()     # filter out non-countries and missing values

values = df[year]
cm = plt.get_cmap('Greens')
scheme = [cm(i / num_colors) for i in range(num_colors)]
bins = np.linspace(values.min(), values.max(), num_colors)
df['bin'] = np.digitize(values, bins) - 1
df.sort_values('bin', ascending=False).head(10)


df['bin'] = np.digitize(values, bins) - 1
df.sort_values('bin', ascending=False).head(10)

print(f'Available Styles: {plt.style.available}')
mpl.style.use('map')
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(22, 12))

ax = fig.add_subplot(111, facecolor='w', frame_on=False)
fig.suptitle(f'Forest area as percentage of land area in {year}', fontsize=30, y=0.95)

m = Basemap(lon_0=0, projection='robin')
m.drawmapboundary(color='w')

m.readshapefile(shapefile, 'units', color='#444444', linewidth=0.2)
for info, shape in zip(m.units_info, m.units):
    iso3 = info['ADM0_A3']
    if iso3 not in df.index:
        color = '#dddddd'
    else:
        color = scheme[df.loc[iso3]['bin']]

    patches = [Polygon(np.array(shape), True)]
    pc = PatchCollection(patches)
    pc._set_facecolor(color)
    ax.add_collection(pc)

# Cover up Antartica so legend can be placed over it
ax.axhspan(0, 1000 * 1800, facecolor='w', edgecolor='w', zorder=2)

# Draw color legend
ax_legend = fig.add_axes([0.35, 0.14, 0.3, 0.3], zorder=3)
cmap = mpl.colors.ListedColormap(scheme)
cb = mpl.colorbar.ColorbarBase(ax_legend, cmap=cmap, ticks=bins, boundaries=bins, orientation='horizontal')
cb.ax.set_xticklabels([str(round(i, 1)) for i in bins])

# Set the map footer
plt.annotate(description, xy=(-0.8, -3.2), size=14, xycoords=0.2)
plt.show()
```

**Full error**

```
/Users/me/.pyenv/versions/3.8.1/bin/python /Users/me/PycharmProjects/ChoroplethMap/chloropleth_map.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/me/PycharmProjects/ChoroplethMap/chloropleth_map.py", line 33, in <module>
    df = df.loc[:, iso3_codes].dropna()     # filter out non-countries and missing values
  File "/Users/me/.pyenv/versions/3.8.1/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py", line 1762, in __getitem__
    return self._getitem_tuple(key)
  File "/Users/me/.pyenv/versions/3.8.1/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py", line 1289, in _getitem_tuple
    retval = getattr(retval, self.name)._getitem_axis(key, axis=i)
  File "/Users/me/.pyenv/versions/3.8.1/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py", line 1954, in _getitem_axis
    return self._getitem_iterable(key, axis=axis)
  File "/Users/me/.pyenv/versions/3.8.1/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py", line 1595, in _getitem_iterable
    keyarr, indexer = self._get_listlike_indexer(key, axis, raise_missing=False)
  File "/Users/me/.pyenv/versions/3.8.1/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py", line 1552, in _get_listlike_indexer
    self._validate_read_indexer(
  File "/Users/me/.pyenv/versions/3.8.1/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py", line 1640, in _validate_read_indexer
    raise KeyError(f"None of [{key}] are in the [{axis_name}]")
KeyError: "None of [Index(['AND', 'ARE', 'AFG', 'ATG', 'AIA', 'ALB', 'ARM', 'AGO', 'ATA', 'ARG',\n       ...\n       'VUT', 'WLF', 'WSM', 'YEM', 'MYT', 'ZAF', 'ZMB', 'ZWE', 'SCG', 'ANT'],\n      dtype='object', length=252)] are in the [columns]"
```

Comment: try `df.reindex(index=iso3_codes)`?

Comment: Did you mean instead of `df = df.loc[:, iso3_codes].dropna()`?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve], as well as the entire error message.

Comment: Do you get the same error when using reindex? no as far as I understand the link you gabe, the `iso3_codes` is a list of elements that should be in index, and `df.loc[:, iso3_codes]` would try to select the element of the list in the column headers

Comment: I've added my code and full error to the question.

Comment: @runnerpaul so I think if you replace `df = df.loc[:, iso3_codes].dropna()` by `df = df.reindex(index=iso3_codes).dropna()` it should work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

replace

```
df = df.loc[:, iso3_codes].dropna()
```

with

```
df = df.reindex(index=iso3_codes).dropna()
```